# Creating a custom Guestbook Module for Alchemy CMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, alchemy-cms

I'm trying to build a guestbook module within a Rails site using the Alchemy CMS framework. There doesn't appear to be much in the way of documentation for module building with Alchemy, so I'm just going off of [this page](http://guides.alchemy-cms.com/creating_modules.html).

I've created two controllers, one that admins will use called guestbook_controller.rb and placed this under app/controllers/admin

```
module Admin
  class GuestbookController < Alchemy::Admin::ResourcesController
    def index
      "index"
    end
  end
end
```

and another for guest to access under app/controllers/guestbook_controller.rb

```
class GuestbookController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    "index"
  end
end
```

My intention is that Guestbook posts will be displayed under one of the pages already within Alchemy and a form will also be displayed on this page.

The guestbook model looks this:

```
class GuestbookEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :location, :message, :name
end
```

My routes file looks like the following:

```
resources :guestbook

namespace :admin do
  resources :guestbook
end

mount Alchemy::Engine => '/'
```

and I have a file called authorization_rules.rb under config that looks like:
    authorization do

```
  role :admin do
    has_permission_on :guestbook, :to => [:manage]
  end

end
```

The first problem that I'm encountering is that going to the route /admin/guestbook gives me the error 'You are not Authorized', but the authorization rules file should be being called by my initalizer, so why am I getting this error?

```
# Registering guestbook module in Alchemy CMS
Alchemy::Modules.register_module(YAML.load_file(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../..', 'config/guestbook_module.yml')))

# Loading authorization rules and register them to auth engine instance
Alchemy::AuthEngine.get_instance.load(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../..', 'config/authorization_rules.rb'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the authorization is easy.
You just need to write:

```
has_permission_on :admin_guestbook, :to => [:manage]
```

Another thing I noticed: Your frontend GuestbookController should inherit from Alchemy::BaseController.

And you should make sure that your page you want to render the guestbook entries on, must not be cached by Alchemy. You can do this by using `cache: false` option in the page_layouts.yml for your page layout.